# specify values in Simple Form Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, simple-form

I am trying to select specific record but when trying to save , `employee_id` is saved with a null value, and without putting any condition it works normally , is there any way to solve this ?

```
<%= f.association :employee , collection:
Employee.where('student_advisor' => true).map(&:full_name) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
<%= f.association :employee, :collection => Employee.where('student_advisor' => true), :label_method => :full_name, :value_method => :id %>
```

Though IMHO its better to set that query in your controller to keep the logic out of your views...

So in the controller:

```
@employee_list = Employee.where('student_advisor' => true)
```

And in the view:

```
<%= f.association :employee, :collection => @employee_list, :label_method => :full_name, :value_method => :id %>
```

Comment: still saving employee_id as null

Comment: Really? if you look at the html source do you see the value in the select on the form?  e.g. `<option value="4">John Doe</option>`

Comment: Also you might try changing the `f.association :employee` to `f.input :employee_id` and pass the collection.

Comment: the first answer solved it there was a mistyping by me in the view and i have fixed it then it worked , thanks alot :)